# Total capacitance at output of source follower

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, cmos, cutoff-frequency

This is the voltage gain of source follower at high frequency.

What I am confused here is why Cdb1, Cdg1 are not included in the pole of the transfer function?

Should it be Cgs2 + Csb2 + CL + Cdb1 + Cgd1 instead of Cgs2 + Csb2 + CL?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. All the capacitances connected to output must be taken into count while calculating frequency response. They may be neglected because of their values.